# Replace brackets from a number in following format ($n) e.g. ($57,282,341.26) with -$57,282,341.26 using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I was working on Globalization currency formatting and I came through an issue where all the currency values in minus is showing brackets instead of minus symbol eg.-$57,282,341.26  is being shown as ($57,282,341.26). 
    Now I wanted to make a global search and replace on such type of strings. So that I could get results as -$57,282,341.26

I tried:

```
var str = "This sentence contains ($57,282,341.26) "; 
var patt1 = /(\()+(\$)+([0-9,.]+)+(\))/g;
var result = str.match(patt1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

I am able to find number in ($n) format but I couldn't do replace with back reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = str.replace(/\((\$[0-9][.,0-9]*)\)/g, '-$1');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVFYep/1)

**Details**:

- `\(` - a literal `(` char
- `(\$[0-9][.,0-9]*)` - Group 1 capturing `$`, a digit and then 0+ digits, `.` or `,` chars
- `\)` - a literal `)` char.

The `-$1` replacement pattern contains a literal `-` symbol and the `$1` backreference to the value kept in Capturing group 1.

```js
var str = "This sentence contains ($57,282,341.26) "; 
var patt1 = /\((\$[0-9][.,0-9]*)\)/g;
var result = str.replace(patt1, "-$1");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think the correct pattern would be `/(?:\()(\$\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*\.\d{1,2})(?:\))/g`.

Comment: @inarilo :There is no point in using non-capturing groups like `(?:\()`, it is equal to `\(`. Then, what can be considered correct is a moot question, my solution above is "good-enough", until OP provides more details. The float number regex is a known thing, I have answered many of them, but here it is not validation that is important, just making sure there is a number inside parentheses.

Comment: I agree that non-capturing groups are not needed but since she is dealing with monetary values, I think the pattern does matter. Though I do realise it is not what she was asking. Just thought it should be pointed out.

Comment: @inarilo I agree with Wiktor (whose answer is exemplary IMHO) that the regex is "good enough"; it will work well in and can be used with confidence until there are actual scenarios found where it is shown to not work.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion, I like to preemptively handle all error situations I can think of than wait for it to fail.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

($57,282,341.26)
I propose you to capture it into 3 groups

```
 1. (\() - "("
 2. (.*) - all inside bracets
 3. (\)) - ")"
```

and now in notepad++ choose replace, click on regex radibutton and 
first put $0-  it should replace "(" to "-"
than $2  it will replace ")" with nothing

please try